# awk to divide an individual file into multiple files with particular file names

Tags: file, awk, sed

I have an original file which have data in below particular format:

```
$ cat sample.txt
>MA0002.1   RUNX1
A  [    10     12      4      1      2      2      0      0      0      8     13 ]
C  [     2      2      7      1      0      8      0      0      1      2      2 ]
G  [     3      1      1      0     23      0     26     26      0      0      4 ]
T  [    11     11     14     24      1     16      0      0     25     16      7 ]
>MA0003.1   TFAP2A
A  [     0      0      0     22     19     55     53     19      9 ]
C  [     0    185    185     71     57     44     30     16     78 ]
G  [   185      0      0     46     61     67     91    137     79 ]
T  [     0      0      0     46     48     19     11     13     19 ]
>MA0003.3   TFAP2C
A  [  1706    137      0      0     33    575   3640   1012      0     31   1865 ]
C  [  1939    968   5309   5309   1646   2682    995    224     31   4726    798 ]
G  [   277   4340    139     11    658   1613    618   5309   5309    582   1295 ]
T  [  1386     47      0    281   2972    438     56      0      0     21   1350 ]
```

I want to divide this file into individual files based on letter `>` and I know that this character appears after every 5th line. I can do this by:

```
awk 'NR%5==1{x="F"++i;}{print > x}' sample.txt
```

problem is it creates multiple files correctly but file names are F1, F2 and F3 respectively, and without any extension. I want to save this individual files by the names mentioned in their first line, which are  `RUNX1`, `TFAP2A` and `TFAP2C` and with an extension of `.pfm`.

So that final files will look like:

```
$ cat RUNX1.pfm
>MA0002.1   RUNX1
A  [    10     12      4      1      2      2      0      0      0      8     13 ]
C  [     2      2      7      1      0      8      0      0      1      2      2 ]
G  [     3      1      1      0     23      0     26     26      0      0      4 ]
T  [    11     11     14     24      1     16      0      0     25     16      7 ]

$ cat TFAP2A.pfm
>MA0003.1   TFAP2A
A  [     0      0      0     22     19     55     53     19      9 ]
C  [     0    185    185     71     57     44     30     16     78 ]
G  [   185      0      0     46     61     67     91    137     79 ]
T  [     0      0      0     46     48     19     11     13     19 ]
```

and so on..

Thank you for taking out the time to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
awk '/^>/{if(file){close(file)};file=$2".pfm"} {print > file".pfm"}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form with explanation too here.

```
awk '
/^>/{             ##Checking here if any line starts with ">" if yes then do following actions.
  if(file){       ##Checking if value of variable named file is NOT NULL, if condition is TRUE then do following.
    close(file)   ##close is awk out of the box command which will close any opened file, so that we could avoid situation of too many files opened at a time.
};
  file=$2".pfm"   ##Setting variable named file to 2nd filed of the line which starts from ">" here.
}
{
print > file".pfm"##Printing the value of current line to file".pfm" which will create file with $2 and .pfm name and put output into output files.
}
' Input_file      ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

***EDIT:***

```
awk '/^>/{if(file){close(file)};array[$2]++;file=array[$2]?(array[$2]==1?$2:$2"."array[$2]):$2} {print > file".pfm"}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This will not `close` even a single file opened, because you got `file=$2` and you are writing to `file".pfm"`,  `file != file".pfm"`, make `awk '/^>/{if(file)close(file); file=$2".pfm"}{print > file}' infile`

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation. I have a problem here. Sometimes same name is used 2 or 3 times. For example, there were 3 lines having start as: `>MA0018.1       CREB1`, `>MA0018.2       CREB1` and `>MA0018.3       CREB1`, only 1 file was saved in this case. Can this be done that if file with that name exists then save them as name.1.pfm and name.2.pfm and so on.. Thanks!

Comment: @Newbie, could you please test it once, I believe I tested with a tag coming multiple occurrence and it is concatenating the lines into same file, let me know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It is saving file as `CREB1.pfm.pfm` and yes have all three occurences. But I want them not in one but in multiple versions, as I explained earlier, ideally it should be in separate files with names: `CREB1.1.pfm`, `CREB1.2.pfm` and so on.

Comment: @Newbie, all your requirements should appear in the question, not scattered in comments.

Comment: @Newbie, please check my EDIT and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @Newbie, please do let me know why you have removed my answer as correct one??

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I was going through my old questions and I thought this question was without accepting any answer, therefore, based on my comment to the selected answer (on Oct 26 '17 at 15:41), I selected that answer. I did not realize that I had accepted your answer in the past(may be it was very low that's why). Please let me know if this was the case, I will again select your answer! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Newbie, it is up to you, I tried to help you, rest it fully up to you.

Comment: @Newbie, though changing your answer later doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 As I said earlier, I could not see that I had already accepted your answer. I couldn't see that green tick and thought this question is still without accepting any answer, therefore, based on that answer in the top and my comment of that answer that "That's what I exactly wanted to do", I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 2):

**That's it**

```
awk -v RS=">" '{print RS$0 > $2".pfm"; close($2".pfm")}' file
```

**To save a new file if the file with the same name was already saved then use this one :**

```
awk -v RS=">" '{a[$2]++; if(a[$2]>1) file=$2"."a[$2]; else file=$2; print RS$0 > file".pfm" ; close(file".pfm")}' file
```

For eg. if **TFAP2A.pfm** was saved before then new file will be saved as **TFAP2A.2.pfm**  **TFAP2A.3.pfm** .... and so on

OR Simply

```
awk -v RS=">" '{file=$2"."++a[$2]; print RS$0 > file".pfm" ; close(file".pfm")}' file
```

If you want to save each file with version Ex. **abc.1.pfm abc.2.pfm**

Comment: IMHO, this could get error "Too many files opened" in case there are many files, so putting close(file_name) could increase beauty of this.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks Ravinder. Done that. (y)

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. I have a problem here. Sometimes same name is used 2 or 3 times. For example, there were 3 lines having start as: >MA0018.1 CREB1, >MA0018.2 CREB1 and >MA0018.3 CREB1, only 1 file was saved in this case. Can this be done that if file with that name exists then save them as name.1.pfm and name.2.pfm and so on.. Thanks!

Comment: @Newbie, I have commented on same under my code, I think my code should take care of it, I did a simple test and for a TAG which is coming multiple times, it is concatenating it in same name file only.

Comment: @Newbie:  Check the updated solution with version control

Comment: @batMan Perfect.. The middle solution is the one I wanted. Many thanks!

Comment: @Newbie: Cheers !!

Comment: @batMan Can you please help me with this question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517279/file-proccessing-by-awk-or-grep

Comment: @Newbie: Here you go mate!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/49537656/8300271

Answer (score 1):

**awk** approach:

```
awk 'NR%5==1{ fn=$2".pfm" }fn{ print > fn}' file
```

---

Or the same using `>` mark:

```
awk '/^>/{ fn=$2".pfm" }fn{ print > fn}' file
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517279/file-proccessing-by-awk-or-grep

Answer (score 1):

Below one takes care, if name is used more than one time

One-liner:

```
awk '/>/{f=$2 (a[$2]++?"."a[$2]-1:"") ".pfm"; if(f!=p){ close(p); p=f}}{print >f}' file
```

Better Readable:

```
 awk '/>/{
           f=$2 (a[$2]++?"."a[$2]-1:"") ".pfm"; 
           if(f!=p){ 
                close(p); 
                p=f
           }
          }
          {
            print >f
          }
     ' file
```

Input:

```
$ cat file
>MA0002.1   RUNX1
A  [    10     12      4      1      2      2      0      0      0      8     13 ]
C  [     2      2      7      1      0      8      0      0      1      2      2 ]
G  [     3      1      1      0     23      0     26     26      0      0      4 ]
T  [    11     11     14     24      1     16      0      0     25     16      7 ]
>MA0003.3   TFAP2C
A  [  1706    137      0      0     33    575   3640   1012      0     31   1865 ]
C  [  1939    968   5309   5309   1646   2682    995    224     31   4726    798 ]
G  [   277   4340    139     11    658   1613    618   5309   5309    582   1295 ]
T  [  1386     47      0    281   2972    438     56      0      0     21   1350 ]
>MA0003.1   TFAP2A
A  [     0      0      0     22     19     55     53     19      9 ]
C  [     0    185    185     71     57     44     30     16     78 ]
G  [   185      0      0     46     61     67     91    137     79 ]
T  [     0      0      0     46     48     19     11     13     19 ]
>MA0003.3   TFAP2C
A  [  1706    137      0      0     33    575   3640   1012      0     31   1865 ]
C  [  1939    968   5309   5309   1646   2682    995    224     31   4726    798 ]
G  [   277   4340    139     11    658   1613    618   5309   5309    582   1295 ]
T  [  1386     47      0    281   2972    438     56      0      0     21   1350 ]
```

Execution:

```
$ awk '/>/{f=$2 (a[$2]++?"."a[$2]-1:"") ".pfm"; if(f!=p){ close(p); p=f}}{print >f}' file
```

Output files:

```
$ ls *.pfm -1
RUNX1.pfm
TFAP2A.pfm
TFAP2C.1.pfm
TFAP2C.pfm
```

Contents of each file:

```
$ for i in *.pfm; do echo "Output File:$i"; cat "$i"; done
Output File:RUNX1.pfm
>MA0002.1   RUNX1
A  [    10     12      4      1      2      2      0      0      0      8     13 ]
C  [     2      2      7      1      0      8      0      0      1      2      2 ]
G  [     3      1      1      0     23      0     26     26      0      0      4 ]
T  [    11     11     14     24      1     16      0      0     25     16      7 ]
Output File:TFAP2A.pfm
>MA0003.1   TFAP2A
A  [     0      0      0     22     19     55     53     19      9 ]
C  [     0    185    185     71     57     44     30     16     78 ]
G  [   185      0      0     46     61     67     91    137     79 ]
T  [     0      0      0     46     48     19     11     13     19 ]
Output File:TFAP2C.1.pfm
>MA0003.3   TFAP2C
A  [  1706    137      0      0     33    575   3640   1012      0     31   1865 ]
C  [  1939    968   5309   5309   1646   2682    995    224     31   4726    798 ]
G  [   277   4340    139     11    658   1613    618   5309   5309    582   1295 ]
T  [  1386     47      0    281   2972    438     56      0      0     21   1350 ]

Output File:TFAP2C.pfm
>MA0003.3   TFAP2C
A  [  1706    137      0      0     33    575   3640   1012      0     31   1865 ]
C  [  1939    968   5309   5309   1646   2682    995    224     31   4726    798 ]
G  [   277   4340    139     11    658   1613    618   5309   5309    582   1295 ]
T  [  1386     47      0    281   2972    438     56      0      0     21   1350 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is also writing in the same file all the occurrences!

Comment: You want to increment file ??

Comment: Yes, each occurence should be stored separately with an increse in file name. for example, in case of CREB1.pfm it will be 3 files with names, CREB1.1.pfm, CREB1.2.pfm and CREB1.3.pfm

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & csplit):

```
csplit -z file '/^>/' '{*}'
sed -ns '1F;1s/^\S\+\s*//p' xx* | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s/^/mv -v /e'
```

Use csplit to do the work of splitting the files up using the pattern `^>` i.e. a `>` at the start of a line signifies new file. Then use two invocations of sed to rename the files. The first outputs the original file name and its intended name. The second adds and executes the move command. Place the files in a separated directory and use `head *` to check the results.