# file proccessing by awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep

I have to process a big input file (2.9 GB) to produce the output in a particular required format (describe below:)

Sample of input file is:

```
GS  RSPH14
CC  Build HSA_Jul2014 (GRCh38; hg38): chr22:23141092..23152092 (REVERSE)
FT  TFBS CHIP: FR000000873; SP1 (Jurkat); PMID:14980218; 23144712..23145380
FT  TFBS CHIP: FR000643682; ER-ALPHA (MCF-7); PMID:19339991; 23147445..23148194
FT  TFBS CHIP: FR029934262; C/EBPBETA (A-549); https://www.encodeproject.org/experiments/ENCSR000DYI/; 23150853..23151108
GS  CLXC15
CC  Build HSA_Jul2014 (GRCh38; hg38): chr3:23144021..23155021 (REVERSE)
FT  TFBS CHIP: FR000643682; ER-ALPHA (MCF-7); PMID:19339991; 23147445..23148194
FT  TFBS CHIP: FR034213319; CTCF (MCF-7); https://www.encodeproject.org/experiments/ENCSR000DMV/; 23151393..23151582
```

Description: Every line in input file starts with either `GS` or `CC` or `FT`, I want to ignore the GS* lines. For the CC* line, I want to split it on `:` and take the `1st index` (0-based counting), according to my input sample it will be `chr22` (in line 2) and `chr3` (in line 7). For the FT line, I want to split it on `;` and take the `1st` and `last index` (according to my input sample's line 3 it will be `SP1 (Jurkat)` and `23144712..23145380`, respectively) and want to proccess them in such a way that my output file should look like this:

```
chr22   23144712    23145380    SP1
chr22   23147445    23148194    ER-ALPHA
chr22   23150853    23151108    C/EBPBETA
chr3    23147445    23148194    ER-ALPHA
chr3    23151393    23151582    CTCF
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

**My Try:** I am able to split the file on `;` so that I get my desired columns. What I tried is: `awk -F'[;]' '{print $2 "\t" $4}' sample.txt > output.txt`. This gives me output as:

```
 hg38): chr22:23141092..23152092 (REVERSE)  
 SP1 (Jurkat)    23144712..23145380
 ER-ALPHA (MCF-7)    23147445..23148194
 C/EBPBETA (A-549)   23150853..23151108

 hg38): chr3:23144021..23155021 (REVERSE)   
 ER-ALPHA (MCF-7)    23147445..23148194
 CTCF (MCF-7)    23151393..23151582
```

Now from the 1st and 6th line I only want `chr22` and `chr3` and from the other lines (non 1st and 6th which were originally starting with `GS` or `CC`) only the last column and append the corresponding chr in front. Also 1st index of other lines should be processed to split on `(` and keep the 1st index.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: This is how far I have reach: `awk -F'[;]' '{print $2 "\t" $4}' sample.txt > output.txt` But I am unable to further split these indices as I require!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain these things, ideally in some more detail (where exactly are you stuck?)

Comment: @tripleee Can you help me now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '
    $1 == "CC" { split($0, a, /:/); key=a[2] }
    $1 == "FT" {
        n = split($0, a, /;/)
        split(a[2], b, FS)
        split(a[n], c, /[.]{2}/)
        print key, c[1],c[2], b[1]
    }
' file | column -t
```

```
chr22  23144712  23145380  SP1
chr22  23147445  23148194  ER-ALPHA
chr22  23150853  23151108  C/EBPBETA
chr3   23147445  23148194  ER-ALPHA
chr3   23151393  23151582  CTCF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out the time to answer. It works perfectly fine. It will be great if you can add short comments with code lines so that I can better understand the solution and modify it according to my needs in future.

Comment: I could not understand what `FS` does in `split(a[2], b, FS)` and please also explain `split(a[n], c, /[.]{2}/)` this line. Thanks!

Comment: `FS` is the regular field separator; so the line is first split on semicolons, and then one of those fields is split in turn on whitespace. `[.]{2}` matches two adjacent literal dots.

Comment: In this case, the contents of FS is already the default separator for split, so this would work too: `split(a[2], b)`

Comment: The GNU awk manual [is here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html), and the `split()` function is [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function)

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/^CC.*/{match($0,/chr[0-9]+/);val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next} /^FT.*/{sub(/\.+/,OFS,$NF);print val,$NF,$5}' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/^CC.*/{
  match($0,/chr[0-9]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  next}
/^FT.*/{
  sub(/\.+/,OFS,$NF);
  print val,$NF,$5}
' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out the time to answer. I have selected the other answer  as it was posted first and I tried and it worked first. Nevertheless, it will be great if you can please add short comments to the code so that I can understand what is happening, so that I can modify it according to my needs in future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

On your request; Using **awk**

```
$ awk '/^CC /{FS=":"; $0=$0; a=$2} /^FT /{FS="[ ;.]+"; $0=$0;print a,$(NF-1),$NF,$5}' file
 chr22 23144712 23145380 SP1
 chr22 23147445 23148194 ER-ALPHA
 chr22 23150853 23151108 C/EBPBETA
 chr3 23147445 23148194 ER-ALPHA
 chr3 23151393 23151582 CTCF
```

`/^CC /{FS=":"; $0=$0; a=$2;}` : If record starts with `CC`(mind the space) set `:` as FS.
`$0=$0` will force awk to split the records on the basis of whatever `FS` is.   Set `a` to second field

`/^FT /{FS="[ ;.]+"; $0=$0; print a,$(NF-1),$NF,$5}` : If record starts with `FT`(again, mind the space) set `[ ;.]+` as `FS` which will equate `FS` to repeated  or  `;` or `.` for ex. `..` as in your last field.
At last, print the required fields.